# Эффективная сортировка ArrayList

Tags: java

Нужно написать реализацию функции
void merge(ArrayList a, ArrayList b) { // тело функции }

Функция принимает два отсортированных от меньшего к большему ArrayList одинакового размера [a1, a2, ..., an], [b1, b2, ..., bn].
В результате выполнения функции в первом(!) ArrayList (в данном случае это А) должны содержаться элементы обоих ArrayList, также отсортированные от меньшего к большему.
Второй ArrayList должен остаться неизменненным.
Пример:
Входные данные
A [1,3,5]
B [2,6,8]
Результат
A [1,2,3,5,6,8]
B [2,6,8]

```
ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
a.add(1);
a.add(3);
a.add(5);

ArrayList b = new ArrayList();
b.add(2);
b.add(6);
b.add(8);

merge(a,b);

void merge(ArrayList a, ArrayList b){
    a.addAll(b);
    Collections.sort(a);
}
```

помогите разобраться, в чем неэффективный код?

Comment: Почему Вы считаете что код неэффективен?

Comment: Ваша проблемма в том, что вы используете уже готовую реализацию сортировки(quick sort помойму в последних версиях) для метода, который будет использоватся для сортировки.
Почитайте про алгоритмы сортировок, marge и quick sorts

Answer (score 2):

Не эффективность заключается в том, что ты сначала сливаешь два списка, а потом сортируешь. Сортируя, sort() проходит по всему списку не один раз.

Есть другой, более эффективный способ. У тебя два списка отсортированных по возрастанию. Так пройдись в цикле по первому и вставляй элементы второго, где это необходимо. Таким образом ты пройдешь по списку один раз и эффективность будет N, а при сортировке N^2.

Comment: А с проверкой на правильность вставки, со всеми преобразованиями, разве не будет трудоемкостнее чем сортом() пробежаться?

Comment: Но мне придется бежать по двум массивам, плюс сама вставка в массив тоже будет не из легких.

Comment: Еще раз. sort() будет проходить по массиву раз за разом. А в предложенном способе, самое сложное это прописать условие для слияния. Посмотри на примере Merge Sort. Станет понятнее о чем я говорю.

Answer (score 1):

У Вас есть два отсортированных списка. Все, что Вам нужно - это вставить элементы из второго списка в нужные позиции в первом списке. Вы же добавляете их в конец убиваете всю сортировку и вынуждены сортировать все заново

Но постоянная вставка элементов для `ArrayList` (в отличии от `LinkedList`) это весьма трудоемкая операция (т.к. нужно постоянно сдвигать элементы вправо). Поэтому Вы должны определиться, что для Вас важнее - минимизировать расход памяти или максимизировать скорость работы? Если на память никаких условий не накладывается, то эффективнее будет получить все значения в третьем списке, а потом перезалить их в первый

Comment: должен быть и минимизирован расход памяти и максимизирована скорость работы :) А разве создание еще одного с перезаливкой в первый не трудоемкий процесс?

Comment: @Reason Так не бывает. Всегда или-или

Comment: @Reason Нет. Там обычное копирование одного куска памяти в другое место